# updating the remote search path for git operations

Tags: git, ssh

When performing operations such as push, rename branch and various others, git uses the search path on the remote machine to find either the standalone executable or git itself to carry out the operations requested. Whether they are standalone or git depends to a large part on how git is compiled - with them included or not.

I have a remote repository that I want to use as the remote of a local repository. Because I have limited access to the remote I am having trouble setting the path correctly so that git on the remote end finds the required executables.

I have tried - for the remote account I am using for authentication - .rc, .bashrc, .profile, .ssh/environment, .ssh/config (RemoteCommand). To this point none of them have worked. The last isn't supported on the version of ssh in use.

On the git side I have tried using git hooks. pre-receive-objects solves some of the problem but other things like push origin -u  fails with a cannot find unpack-objects, cannot find gc error. I have updated all the other hooks that appear germane

I would prefer a solution that was like the .profile solution - a script run at each connect by git. I will take whatever I can get.

Question: How do I reliably add a new directory/location to the search path used on a remote machine during git operations.

Edit:

- Git version 2.9.5.
- OS: Linux: Kernel 2.6.39
- bash GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
  Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
- ssh OpenSSH_6.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014

Sample hook file that didn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to make use of push options.
# The example simply echoes all push options that start with 'echoback='
# and rejects all pushes when the "reject" push option is used.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-receive".

EXPORT PATH=$PATH:/home/paulc/bin
```

.profile example that doesn't work:

```
# /etc/skel/.bashrc
#
# This file is sourced by all *interactive* bash shells on startup,
# including some apparently interactive shells such as scp and rcp
# that can't tolerate any output.  So make sure this doesn't display
# anything or bad things will happen !


# Test for an interactive shell.  There is no need to set anything
# past this point for scp and rcp, and it's important to refrain from
# outputting anything in those cases.
if [[ $- != *i* ]] ; then
        export PATH=$PATH:/home/paulc/bin

        # Shell is non-interactive.  Be done now!
        return
fi


# Put your fun stuff here.
export PATH=$PATH:/home/paulc/bin
```

Comment: This depends on the OS and Git installation on the remote machine, so you'll need to name both of those.

Comment: Updated with some versions etc as askef for by torek. Happy to add more.

Comment: It would help if you could show us the *specific* things you've tried; otherwise we're liable to simply suggest them to you as answers.

Comment: a couple of examples tried. Essentially I was just doing the standard export path thing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, on *Ubuntu* Linux systems:

- The `$PATH` that *all* programs start with by default is set in `/etc/environment`.
- The `$PATH` that *cgi scripts* started with Apache, assuming you're using Apache as your web server for `https` traffic, *might* be different but might be inherited from this `/etc/environment` (I've never personally set up Apache).  If you're using some other http(s) server, consult its documentation.
- The `$PATH` that *ssh* connections will get will default to whatever path *you* get when you log in and don't have a `.profile` or `.bashrc`: that is, the `$PATH` from `/etc/environment` *unless* it's overridden by `/etc/profile` and/or the files in `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.  (This assumes you're using bash or similar.)  See more details below.

For more on *Ubuntu-specific* settings, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile.  For more generic web-server information, see [Setting $PATH for weberver user](https://serverfault.com/q/418952/549786).  Note that ServerFault is generally the right place for these kinds of questions.

Note that when you use ssh to connect, though, *your login shell* runs.  Whatever you have set up as your login shell, it will load whatever profile or bashrc or zshrc or whatever files its documentation says it will load.  In these files, you can:

- Test to see if it's an interactive and/or login shell: this is sometimes important, so that you can avoid producing output that will confuse programs like Git.  The method for testing "is this a login shell" is shell-specific, but for bash, `$-` will contain the flag `i` if it's *interactive* and `l` if it's a *login shell*.
- Set `$PATH` however you like.

This setting will be passed on to all commands run *by* this shell, including those requested by `ssh`.  So if you use an ssh URL to connect to your Linux system, and use bash or dash or sh or one of that crowd, you can put instructions in `$HOME/.profile` and/or `$HOME/.bashrc`.

> .profile example that doesn't work:
>
> ```
> # /etc/skel/.bashrc
> ```

If you've modified `/etc/skel/.bashrc` itself, this won't help; if you've placed the contents shown in `$HOME/.profile`, that should affect *ssh* Git connections.  It won't affect *https* ones.

> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/home/paulc/bin
> ```

In general, I put my own personal binaries and scripts first, so that I can override the system ones:

```
export PATH="$(_makepath ...)"
```

(where `_makepath` is a fancy—perhaps overly fancy—function I wrote for my own amusement; it's in [this file](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/Dotfiles/sh-common)).

Comment: Not sure this answers the question. As stated I have limited access - no root which would be required. SSH is not calling local startup scripts - unless there is one that I have missed. The git hook scripts don't seem to be broad enough to cover all remote activity.

Comment: Hook scripts are indeed not broad enough. If you don't have the correct access to the remote, you can't fix broken stuff on the remote. If you do everything through ssh access *to your own account* to which you have access, you can set *your own* path. But otherwise you need superuser access. (By the way, I took "limited access" to mean "can only *log in* at certain hours, but do have superuser access in general".)

Comment: "If you do everything through ssh access to your own account". So the remotes are set up to use ssh to the repository and they use my account credentials. I am not sure whether is is ssh to my account. It doesn't appear to be running .profile. So either I have done something wrong, this is non usual behavior or I have misunderstood you.

Comment: What login shell do you use? I use bash on Linux systems, and it runs my `.profile` (`$HOME/.profile`); I can `ssh <linux-host>` and I get my bash prompt, as set in my dot-files. If I put `export PATH=...` in them it affects all commands including Git ones.

Comment: bash and it appears to run one of the startup scripts but this doesn't seem to be the case when git is using ssh. Otherwise it would be simple

Comment: It really should work then. Some Linuxes have `dash` installed as `/bin/sh` and dash has some oddities (I'm not sure what they all are) but that should never affect *bash*, which should always be some version of bash. All versions should source your `.profile` at startup.